# Google static maps - Weird/contrasting behavior on BlackBerry simulator and PC Browser

Tags: google-maps, blackberry, google-maps-api-3, blackberry-simulator, httpconnection

I am stuck with a weird problem. I am trying to download a Google Static maps image by executing a simple URL in my application, but the image seems to be very different from what i see on my PC browser.

The catch is that I am trying to display the driving directions between 2 lat/long points using overview polyline points (obtained using Google Maps Direction Api). As expected the overview_polyline points are large and contain a lot of special characters..like below

overview_polyline: {
levels: "B@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@A@@@@@@@@A@@@@@@@@A@@@@A@@@A@@@@@@@@@@@@@A@@@@@@@@@@@@@@A@@A@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@A@@@@@@@@@@@@@@A@@A@@@@@@A@@@@@@A@@@@@@@B"
points: "sfdnAunkxM`Ak[yKiKdbAhn@pPzZbMns@tr@tjAvKbb@ru@zq@rMl{@leAhsA`KpUhu@ps@bMzDdXheAzZzXd\|k@~ZnUdYzb@jmA|s@~UrYxe@lRj~@px@|qAzf@fb@d_@`c@~QfrAjTh`BvhAtM`c@nSdWpC~[|k@tp@jr@dd@bd@deAjV~SvKffBtI~[~u@zt@tMn^heAfh@h[fj@~XzVpWjnAxSlTeIro@tEvNzP|JvTgDbl@zBdfAdyAbe@baApg@hc@fJr]tb@vf@fPdElQ|Ulc@`YzLpUvtApq@f_@xGHnZwHpb@|Qde@tIdj@gAv\dYngA`Fn`AtOhp@|^jlDvf@pdAhKns@dv@|tApHn`@xVj`@vBfxCnLpPl`BjGtlA`}Ala@||Afo@nfB|Epi@faCftFtHl``` @q@vg@_In^jJ``BpHlUf_ApcA|c@dz@bKbfDjjAfkCv ```@dzA~x@lrBpCx\jJlVpNhuBhHhYtQzc@|[`Xtu@byA|p@bz@`Z|n@xu@p_@xNnRfo@vc@bSzZhJjc@w@|m@ru@`{@jCda@jInSpmApk@s@dp@{Hpl@pDnRhn@nO~uA`C`_@zJ|hAoBpd@~L|WzRxeARmDva@hKxPv@lVj]pCvA~Cvg@~@z@nHxa@yAboAxKnUyFjh@w]nk@uMfXlErRuCUsE"
}

---

Will it be a problem to use this on BlackBerry, does it have any side-effect when excuted using httpconnection. I am suspecting a User-Agent issue, but not sure..

Here's the url i am trying to download - Direction from New York to New Jersey

[http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap...](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?size=360x240&markers=color%3ablue&path=weight:3%7Ccolor%3ared%7Cenc%3au~nwFtjubMsC%7CH%7BSmOoCa@uOZo@N%7BB%60E%7BF~HMEKg@iAaBgAg@iBCw@b@q@%60A%5DlBuB%7C%5CuEzm@iD%7C%60@sDhi@uDjSqCjEcBbE_Cpl@PnFUtRXzC%60@lAzAlBvF%7CC~Bz@rf@%60MvVbGbC%60@zCTnCEbC%5BbBg@rLoF~Co@jCA%60CT%7CBh@jDpBhBnB~@bBlTdj@%7CDpGbDxDz@l@hJfJtD%60FhB~ClDrIfAtD~FlXdChHlDfH~FhIba@ja@xCjD%60ExG~B%60FbB%60FlBhI~@jIDxESpEi@zEm@zBqArCsBzC%7BNnRiAtBuBjFaBlGoDxPov@tuDwEnSyDjNkHhS%7BCtJgGfW%7B@%60B%5DXs@Ba@YQkAX%7D@%7C@YbALnPvGpRbJtK%60HhWdNd@J%60H%60ErQfL%7CfArp@%60PrK~FrE%7CL%60Lbk@fj@fNpJrf@rX%7CBzBhDjExClFz%5Cfu@lF%60IbClCzEzDxElCl%5ClNr%5DrRf%5C~Or%5CpQfdAdi@lo@h%5CxN%60HjS%7CL%60WpQvRhJdIxCdKrEvz@td@vWfQhMrKvv@rs@%7Cc@%7Cb@bR%7CRrIzKbOfUtHlN%7CJnRtGdNhEjKtG%7CQ~AdGvDzQbDxTpH%7Cl@%60ApJrFft@t@nI~@dHjGd%5EvFhUjE%7CMvD%60KlChGjG%60MrTr_@zEjJvFrLpGzOfQrg@lXl_AdDvJvF~M~BbFbKtQjF%7CHnFfHfUpWteClvCjHjIxIbJzLtJf%5EbUfPhLdLzGj%60Axf@%7CvB%7CeAdLdG%7Cy@zi@lc@%7C%5BfYxRhVxMtKfFbPtGhKfDxy@vTxtFzbB%60WrIb%5BtMfClBfAvAf@lATpATxHZdCfArB%7CAt@~RlE%60D%60BfAxAFfAOx@m@d@c@BiAa@sHkEy@Fe@t@%7B@tFrQbFvPbEz@@hH%60BpUbG~An@nA%60AzPlRds@l%7B@gClNkFbc@dDp@xEl@ntAnO@i@eFm@&sensor=false)

Comment: I'm not clear on your question.  Are you asking whether this will work on BlackBerry?  Or are you saying that you tried it on your BB, but that the image looks different when displayed on your BB than it does when displayed on your desktop computer?  Or are you trying to compare the output of the Static Maps API with the output of the full JavaScript Google Maps experience?  Please clarify.

Comment: Hi scott, thanks for your reply. The Google maps api is working fine. The problem is the static image that is displayed on my desktop computer is the correct one which interprets the directions properly, but when the same url is executed on a BB silulator, the image that is downloaded seems to be different, ie, it would be displaying a static image of some unknown location.

Comment: Ah, have you made sure that you URL escape your entire URL as needed, including the data that you are receiving from the directions API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is a blackberry thing.  I was having the same issue and it actually was because the polyline most likely has some characters that need to be escaped before creating a url.  You can do it in ruby with `URI.escape(string)` or just google for a utility that you prefer to do it for you.  I see that Scott W. above already posted this so I voted it up, but maybe you are waiting for it to pop up as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Google maps](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Limits) and charts (both static images) on [my website](http://preferans.de/top20.php) and while browsing it with a BB phone I often see a static image which is shown, when over 1000 requests have been made from the same IP address (probably because many BB users have the same public IP address). Maybe you have a similar problem?

[image]

Or maybe you just pass wrong URL parameters in Blackberry, because you haven't escaped some character (like quote or backslash...)